# Parsing to JSON in python when exposed with boost::python

Tags: python, c++, json, boost-python

I am trying to expose a structure in C++ to a python script, which then converts the structure to a JSON format. The structure contains both vector as well as elementary datatypes. So my approach was to scan through the attributes of the structure, if it is a elementary datatype, then just add it to the dictionary. Else, scan through the list, and add all the elementary datatypes.

So here is what I came up with:

```
# Get all the attributes of the object, also ensure it is not a function.
def getattribs(obj):
    return [i for i in dir(obj) if not i.startswith('__') and not callable(getattr(obj, i))]

def f(obj):
    for i in getattribs(obj):

        # Ensure it is not a list
        if not hasattr(getattr(obj, i), '__iter__'):
            print((i, getattr(obj, i)))

        else:
            for x in list(getattr(obj, i)):

                # If obj is string, then just add it
                if(isinstance(x, basestring)):
                    print((i, x))
                else:
                    f(x)
```

But as you can see, parsing it to JSON from this point on becomes a pain in the ass. Is there any better way to do the same?

Sample structure in C++:

```
struct Hosts {
        std::string hostName;
        bool isProvider;
        bool showVM;
        std::vector<std::string> vmList;
        bool operator==(Hosts const& h) const { return h.hostName == hostName; }
};

struct ClustersInfo {
        std::string clusterName;
        bool showChild;
        std::vector<Hosts> hosts;
        bool operator==(ClustersInfo const& ci) const {
                return ci.clusterName == clusterName;
        }
};


struct Clusters {
        bool expanded;
        std::vector<ClustersInfo> clusterInfo;
        void populateData();
        Clusters getData();
};
```